# debug.log file is empty in Magento 2.2.x

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, log

After upgrading a site from Magento 2.1.x to 2.2.3, log output is no longer being written to `var/log/debug.log`. There was nothing in the [2.2.0 change log](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.0CE.html) about this behavior.

Answer (score 6):

Magento 2.2.0 added a "Log to File" option in *STORES > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer*:

[image]

By default, this option is disabled. If you enable this option, content will be written to `var/log/debug.log` again. If you are in the backend of a site in production mode, you won't see this configuration field. You'll need to manually change this setting in the database using a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
VALUES
    ('default', 0, 'dev/debug/debug_logging', '1');
```

Note #1: caution should be taken before enabling logging on a site running in production to avoid private data being written to this log file.

Note #2: Logging behavior for shipping/payment methods is changing in *2.2.4*, per this note in [the change log](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.4CE.html): *Magento now provides dedicated payment and shipping debug log files to store information specific to those functional areas.*